# How to push submit data into existing local json file?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got an assignment, and I'm new to angular. I have to push data that comes from submitting a form into an existing json file I have locally. My assignment is to create an angular application where a user can create new tasks and then view them on a different page.

I tried to use http.post, but was unsuccessful, I then for some reason thought pushing might work, since the json is an array, but that didn't work really because I'm sort of clueless lol.

Here is what my json file looks like, the requirements also state I have to have one hard coded in, so this what it looks like:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "name": "Dishes",
            "timeToComplete": "10 Minutes",
            "description": "Cleaning the dishes",
            "itemsNeeded": "Soap, Sponge, Water, Dirty Dishes!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the html code of the component that has the form:

```
    <div>
    <h3>Create A New Task</h3>
    <form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
        <label for='name'>Name of Task:</label>
        <input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Name' name='name' 
    required [(ngModel)]='task.name' />
        <br>
        <label for='time'>Estimated Time to Complete:</label>
        <input type='text' id='time' placeholder='Time' name='timeToComplete' required
            [(ngModel)]='task.timeToComplete' />
        <br>
        <label for='description'>Description of Task:</label>
        <input type='text' id='description' placeholder='Description' name='description' required
            [(ngModel)]='task.description' />
        <br>
        <label for='itemsNeeded'>Items to complete task:</label>
        <textarea type='text' id='itemsNeeded' placeholder='Items' name='itemsNeeded' required
            [(ngModel)]='task.itemsNeeded'></textarea>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        <p>If all looks good, go ahead and hit submit!</p>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <div>
        <h1>Here's what your task looks like: </h1>
        <h3>Your Task: {{ task.name }}</h3>
        <h4>Time it will take: </h4><p>{{ task.timeToComplete }}</p>
        <h4>Description of what you will be doing: </h4><p>{{ task.description }}</p>
        <h4>What you will need, to succeed! </h4><p>{{ task.itemsNeeded }}</p>
    </div>


</div>
```

The code you see below I just made to see if the inputs are wired correctly. and finally here is my .ts file of the component, including the onSubmit function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../../models/task';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
selector: 'app-tasks',
templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
  task: Task = new Task();
  url = '../../../extask.json';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
 onSubmit() {
console.log('Submit came through', this.task);
this.http.post(this.url, this.task)
}
}
```

The console works and shows the object being returned from the submit, so I know that works, but how would I go about adding this to the json file above?

Comment: what is the ouput from the http?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Not really sure I completely understand your question, because the http isn't outputting anything

Comment: #1 what is the data format that you are trying to push?
#2 your question is seeking help to push data to your json file, do you you mean write to that file?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more about the output from the http? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly save JSON file from simple js, you need a backend server in **nodejs** or some script to handle the request.

Though you can save the json to the browser cache using.

```
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

and get it by using

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the JSON file by Ajax, Websocket or whatever and parse it to a object or array first.

```
  result = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now you have in your memory a nice Object or Array. On that object you can do your changes.

In case you have to hard code it that more easy ;)

```
var data = {
"tasks": [
    {
        "name": "Dishes",
        "timeToComplete": "10 Minutes",
        "description": "Cleaning the dishes",
        "itemsNeeded": "Soap, Sponge, Water, Dirty Dishes!"
    }
]
}
```

now its also in mem an can be changed. It is a bit confusing to deal with JSON first times. "{" means OBJECCT aka dictionary and "[" means ARRAY. In your case you has a object/dictionary first. So someones wants to have a lot of things in the data structure (application colors, name of the company cat) and finally one object is to be all the TASKS. Task implicitly means there might be more the one. So he use next a ARRAY to store all tasks. And for sure a task can have also a lot of things to be considered so he stores that in a OBJECT. Like your html code shows also.

now you can read out your form
and do something like this

```
 taskdata ={}     // create a empty OBJECT/Dictionary
 taskdata.name=document.forms["you forget to name your form ;) "].name.value;
 taskdata.name=document.forms["you forget to name your form ;) "].
 timeToCompleten.value;
 //and so on
```

so the vanilla javascript taskdata holds now all your things and can be serialized to be able to fullfill a POST request.

```
  var data = taskdata.JSON.stringify()
```

Now data has lot of "?" and "&" inside and could be a understandable thing for every POST and GET action;)

```
this.http.post(this.url, taskdata)// ive no meaning about angular i code 
 //plain since 
 //over 20 years who needs that :)
```

I guess this "oldschool" code would even work in netscape navigator 4.7 til any firefox or chrome nightly

I can just suggest before to use any fancy "modern" ive no meaning about javascript library or a i am to lazy to type cause i am a hipster" library to read a good book from oReilly Javascript in a nutshell. Can be found even for free on the web. ;) Google might be also a help. To understand the foundation of such a lib is a great way to do ANYTHING. Not just the things they promise or try to force you. Javascript is nowadays f****in fast. But seems we try to brake it in as much as we can by "libs".  .oO(JQuery is best example- trace a "getElementByID" and get worms)